# Specifying IP Address for DNS Migration to Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

I am currently in the process of migrating my DNS to Cloudflare, and I've encountered a bit of a snag that I hope some of you might be able to assist me with.

I am managing a domain registered in Spain, and as part of the migration process to Cloudflare, I am required to update my DNS settings. The registrar specifically requests the name server details, which in my case is iris.ns.cloudflare.com. This part is straightforward.

Along with the name server, **my registrar is also asking for an IP address**. This is where I'm uncertain. Typically, I understand that name servers are identified by their domain names, and not necessarily by an IP address. However, my registrar's system seems to require an IP address to proceed.

My Questions:

- Is it common for registrars to ask for an IP address along with the
  name server?
- What IP address should I provide when using a Cloudflare
  name server like iris.ns.cloudflare.com? Is there a specific IP
  associated with Cloudflare's name servers, or is there a general
  approach I should take in this situation?
- Are there any potentialrisks or considerations I should be aware of when providing an IP address in this context? Any insights, experiences, or guidance on
  this matter would be greatly appreciated. I'm looking to ensure a
  smooth transition without affecting my domain's accessibility.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they require also the ip address because they want to verify connection to the name server.

```
# dig iris.ns.cloudflare.com
; <<>> DiG 9.18.19-1~deb12u1-Debian <<>> iris.ns.cloudflare.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50101
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1224
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;iris.ns.cloudflare.com.                IN      A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
iris.ns.cloudflare.com. 202     IN      A       108.162.192.118
iris.ns.cloudflare.com. 202     IN      A       172.64.32.118
iris.ns.cloudflare.com. 202     IN      A       173.245.58.118
;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER:  (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 11 19:41:25 UTC 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 99
```